# Sharing native screen and values between iOS client and Applet

Tags: ios, objective-c, applet

I want to share my iOS native app screen to a web application(for ex: an Applet) and vice versa. I know that, sharing other’s iOS application screen is not allowed by apple, but we can share our own application screen. I want to do this programmatically. First approach can be sharing screenshot images from iOS native to web, i tested with a sample it worked. But, I have a problem with this. I can’t do this sharing vice versa. i.e,  If i modify something on the web applet, that should reflect back to iOS native screen. For ex: I have a text field in iOS native screen, which is shared to web applet. Lets say I type something in that text field on the applet end, later that value should reflect in iOS native as well. Sharing screen and values on both sides.

Could someone advise me or guide me how can I achieve this please?

Comment: Can you please provide some info, how you have implemented native app sharing over web? Because I guess Apple will not approve such behavior.

Comment: Apps store guidelines: Apps with names, descriptions, or screenshots not relevant to the App content and functionality will be rejected.

Comment: you can share your app screens, not the others

Answer (score 0):

Share your iOS device screen to others

> View the remote iOS device screen in real-time using TeamViewer
>   QuickSupport app. It’s now even easier to connect to and provide
>   support for iPhones and iPads! As long as their device is running iOS
>   11, users can share their screens using the TeamViewer QuickSupport
>   app. Your connection partner simply has to press the button embedded
>   in the chat in the QuickSupport app and the screen sharing will start
>   immediately.

TeamViewer QuickSupport Application: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/teamviewer-quicksupport/id661649585
[image]